# Solution for Git GUI client for remote SSH

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I am a [Git GUI](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) user. I don't have an issue using it for my local development. However, now we have a server with a Git repository. Can I remotely push, pull and diff by using the Git GUI client to access that?

Currently, I am SSHing to the Linux server, and use a Git command to do all the Git commands. But I found it very difficulty when it comes to diff. That's why I think is there any solution for me using the Git GUI client access remote repository and do the Git command with a Git client.

I want to be able to mount a remote server in a Git repository.
Current we only have to open the Git repository in our local disk. For example, the *C:\www\repo.git* file. How about if I want to access 10.10.10.10/home/www/.git and do all the Git commands in the Git client?

Solutions are open for OS X and Windows.

Comment: This is SuperUser (it's reaaally broad, no problem to be reproduced, etc.). Either to be moved or closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server has it enabled, you can use `XForwarding` to display a GUI executed on the remote machine on your local machine.

On the server-side, this means that you need to have the proper tools installed (e.g., `git-gui`, which means that you also need [Tcl/Tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) installed, which means that you also need the `X` infrastructure installed).

You also must enable *Xforwarding*, by making sure that you have a line like the following in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

To use that on your local Linux machine, you would usually use the `-X` flag to enable `XForwarding` for a given connection:

```
 shiro@local:~$ ssh -X gituser@gitserver

 gituser@gitserver:~$ cd repo.git
 gituser@gitserver:~/repo.git$ git gui
```

On your local OS X machine, you would instead use `-Y`:

```
 shiro@applejoice:~$ ssh -Y gituser@gitserver

 gituser@gitserver:~$ cd repo.git
 gituser@gitserver:~/repo.git$ git gui
```

You need an `Xserver` running on your local machine, in order to use `XForwarding`. While this is not a problem on Linux (or OS X), it gets complicated for [Win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). There are [tutorials](https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY) on the web for setting up and using Xservers under Win32 (e.g., `Xming`).

Comment: I checked my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` have the X11Forwarding yes. I can use ssh -X gituser@gitserver.
I need to install gitserver in my local linux machine?

Comment: 'gitserver' is the name of your git server. since you *can use* the command i gave, i don't see any problem.

Comment: Sorry, I means I can't run git gui. When I run `git gui`
git: 'gui' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
 gc
 grep
 init
 pull
 push
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/project$ git-gui
git-gui: command not found

Comment: well, in my answer it says "you need to have the proper tools installed (e.g. git-gui"), which is exactly your problem: you don't have `git gui` installed; so install it.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) / remote X (which is an obvious solution and therefore not worth putting in an answer), the only alternative I can find is [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)'s new remote development support.

You can connect to a server via ssh (from within Visual Studio Code), and then Visual Studio Code's Git features work natively. The interface is fairly basic however - in particular there is no history view and you can't rebase, cherry-pick, etc. from the GUI. It's basically for staging commits.

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) gives you a proper git graph view. It's pretty good.

Comment: This is probably the best solution in 2020. I'm wondering if GitKraken supports this out of the box...

Comment: For Dreamhost.com, I had to run this: setfattr -n user.pax.flags -v "mr" $(find $NVM_DIR -type f -iname "node" -o -iname "npm" -o -iname "npx") which I found at: https://gitmemory.com/issue/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/3201/650809470

Answer (score 1):

First, when it comes to diff, you can simply git fetch your repo, and do the diff locally (with git gui), since you have the all history.

Second, if you have ssh access to the server, you don't need to actually open an ssh session.

A simple `git command git@gitserver:/path/to/git/project.git` is enough (repalce "`command`" with clone/push/pull/fetch)
That means the fetch is easy.

See [Git on the Server - Setting Up the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) for an ssh setup, at least for Linux or Mac.
For Windows, you have alternative ssh server you can consider, like [`copssh-free-edition`](https://www.itefix.net/content/copssh-free-edition).

---

> But now our team is having this issue, and I am the only person in charge for the GIT. That's why I looks for help how to solve this

Then you would need to ssh to the server, git add and git commit there in the repo, then go back to your local workstation, clone or fetch, and do the diff there. –

Comment: My problem is some of our team they are not familiar with GIT. sometimes they go to production server (live server) to make amendment there. That why, server code is messy. I want to check on the server before I make the commit in server. If I can have GIT client connection to remote server, that will be easy my job. 
For your illustration, I still not really get how you setup in remote side (e.g my server IP is 10.10.10.10

Comment: @Shiro no setup required : as long as `ssh git@gitserver ls /path/to/git/project.git` works (meaning you can access and list the content of a bare repo on the server), you can use git command like a `git clone git@gitserver:/path/to/git/project.git`

Comment: First, when it comes to diff, you can simply git fetch your repo, and do the diff locally (with git gui), since you have the all history.
How do I manage fetch my remote repo if I didn't commit it. My idea is I do not want to simply commit my server code before I check it. I don't get what you means

Comment: @Shiro "I am SSH to the linux server, and use git command to do all the git command. ": that means your repo is on your server. I mean you can clone/fetch it locally, and do the diff locally.

Comment: yes. I can clone/fetch it locally. However, my teammate they do the ad-hoc change in the server, and they did not commit it. I can't fetch the latest right? both my local and the server is using bitbucket git server.

Comment: @Shiro It is important indeed that you team does not do any change directly on the server (especially if they are not committed)

Comment: I do understand. But now our team is having this issue, and I am the only person in charge for the GIT. That's why I looks for help how to solve this. I can't force them to learn due to company policy different department...sign..

Comment: @Shiro then you would need to ssh to the server, add and commit, then go back to your local workstation, clone or fetch, and do the diff there.

Comment: as I mention, I do not want to commit first before check. I want to use GIT client to check the different. If there is a GIT client can access remote server repo (10.10.10.10/www/.git) do the all the GIT command in GUI, not in command line (this is the reason I ask for this question).

Comment: @Shiro you need a script (like a cron job) on the server which will detect changes, add and commit there. Then you can do the rest on your local workstation (fetch, diff) with any GUI you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sshfs to mount remote path as local machine file path

```
 sshfs root@xxx.com:/root/yourpath /Users/xxxx/xxx
```

Comment: Similarly Mutagen is great for syncing over SSH https://mutagen.io/

Answer (score 1):

I hacked together [forkgit](https://github.com/brechtm/forkgit), a git proxy that allows [Fork](https://fork.dev/) to work with git checkouts over SSH. I have been using it daily for more than a year alongside Visual Studio Code (Remote SSH). With SSH multiplexing, it's nearly as fast as interacting with a local checkout.

There are some caveats which are described in the README.