# How to connect Git GUI client (GitKraken) over SSH

Tags: git, ssh, gitkraken

Right now I'm working on a project on a remote machine. My laptop runs Windows, and the project needs to be on Linux to run, so it's easier to test this way.

I am coding via SSH over Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial). I've just been SSHing in for git, and using the CLI, but I would like to start using a GUI client on this project. Is there any way to connect GitKraken (or another GUI client) to my remote machine over SSH, without cloning it locally?

Comment: There's a feature request on this topic: https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/198549/ssh-tunneling (at the time of writing it's "under consideration"). I would try mounting a remote path through ssh (look for SSHFS) and opening the now-local folder with gk as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VNC for GitKraken, but here are the instructions for Git GUI:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33424668
———

if your server has it enabled, you can use `XForwarding` to display a GUI executed on the remote machine on your local machine.

On the server-side, this means that you need to have the proper tools installed (e.g. `git-gui`, which means that you also need `tcl/tk` installed, which means that you also need the `X` infrastructure installed).
You also must enable *Xforwarding*, by making sure that you have a line like the following in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

To use that on your local linux machine, you would usually use the `-X` flag to enable `XForwarding` for a given connection:

```
 shiro@local:~$ ssh -X gituser@gitserver
 gituser@gitserver:~$ cd repo.git
 gituser@gitserver:~/repo.git$ git gui
```

On your local OSX machine, you would instead use `-Y`

```
 shiro@applejoice:~$ ssh -Y gituser@gitserver
 gituser@gitserver:~$ cd repo.git
 gituser@gitserver:~/repo.git$ git gui
```

You need an `Xserver` running on your local machine, in order to use `XForwarding`. While this is not a problem on linux (or OSX), it get's complicated for W32. There are [tutorials](https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY) on the web for setting up and using Xservers under W32 (e.g. `Xming`)