# Git ssh is not working on git gui, how to fix that?

Tags: git, ssh

I have setup ssh access using git bash and able to do all the operations on private repos.

But, with Git GUI I am not able to do these operations, it seems not able to pick the ssh key using git gui.

The process I followed is described in this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).

It is working with Git Bash but not working with Git GUI.

[image: GIT GUI]

When I do push form "Git GUI",it is failing
[image: error screen]

When I do push from "Git Bash",it is successful
[image: success from bash]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33305697/4575350

Comment: Does this answer your question? [solution for GIT GUI client for remote SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305697/solution-for-git-gui-client-for-remote-ssh)

Comment: @sta @evolutionxbox I'm not sure the linked question is the same as this one. This question *as I understand it* is about running Git GUI locally and using `ssh://` URLs. The linked question is about running Git GUI remotely on a host being connected to using `ssh`.

Comment: Hi @phd , thank you , you got my question. Git Bash is working for me. Git GUI is not able to access the private data

Comment: @udaykiran Does your ssh key have a passphrase? Do you use `ssh-agent`? Did you run `eval \`ssh-agent\`` and `ssh-add key` in Gitbash?

Comment: No, it doesn't have. And it is working for git bash.And I am using eval command

Answer (score 0):

The warning "`This repository moved. Please use the new location:`" as seen in [this issue](https://github.com/x-motemen/ghq/issues/186), is a bit strange.

Try the  ssh scheme URL `ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo>` to see if there is any difference.

But to set also in your Git bash session the GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable to see more clues:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
```

Comment: There is no problem in ssh using git bash. Problem is with git gui only. Can you suggest how to fix git gui for accessing these repos.?

Comment: @udaykiran: set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'` in the Windows User environment variables, then launch git gui, and see if the logs shows more.

Comment: No use, it is not showing any logs for this. So I tried to fetch from origin and got this error. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Git GUI will look in your `C:\Users\<User>\.ssh` folder for a `config` file. If you add a `config` file (no extension) you can add the paths of your keys. Otherwise git GUI will only look for default key names.
For some reason Git GUI doesn't execute `~/.profile` or  `~/.bashrc` (Git Bash does), which can be used to autostart ssh agent and add keys.

This type of config file worked for me:

```
IdentitiesOnly=yes
PreferredAuthentications publickey
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\id_ed25519_your_key
IdentityFile /c/Users/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519_your_key
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_your_key
```

Any of the three path notations work. See https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config for syntax of the config file.